# How to validate PUT input in ApiPlatform?

Tags: api-platform.com

suppose I have an ApiResource like this:

```
class MyResource {

    const STATUS_A = 'A';
    const STATUS_B = 'B';
    const STATUS_C = 'C';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Choice(
     *      choices = {MyResource::STATUS_A, MyResource::STATUS_B, MyResource::STATUS_C}
     * )
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    private $counter;

    ...

}
```

As you can see, I setup validation constraints so the status value can be STATUS_A, STATUS_B or STATUS_C.

Now, I'd like to also validate the data provided in PUT requests, so that status can only be set to STATUS_A.
For example, the following PUT payload should be accepted:

```
{
  "status": "A"
}

{
  "status": "A",
  "counter: 5
}

{
  "counter": 5
}
```

Instead, the following one should NOT be accepted:

```
{
  "status": "B"
}

{
  "status": "C",
  "counter": 5
}
```

What is the best point to perform validation against data provided by the API client?
I know that I could use validation inside DTOs DataTransformers, but I'm not using DTOs this time.

Thank you. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: have you try with https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation/ ?

or here you have more points to extends api-platform by custom logic https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extending/

Comment: Yes, but validation, in PUT operations, occours after merging the original object (retrieved by the ItemDataProvider) and the request payload data. So, for example, I can have status = "C" but I do not know if the value was already stored in the original object or changed due to an "invalid" request payload.

Comment: So it looks like you have to work with (de)normalization process.

Comment: I think you're right. I tried to decorate the default Denormalizer ApiPlatform service, but I can't find it. Do you know how it is named?

Comment: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#decorating-a-serializer-and-adding-extra-data